# Firestore query is always null inside Firebase Function

Tags: typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firebase Function, which takes data and uses it for querying Firestore.
The query is always returning null, even though there is equivalent data in the database.

I have tried hardcoding the id and it still returns null, so I'm sure the problem is not the data used on the query.

The query:

```
/**
 * Returns a user
 * @param {string} userId the user id.
 * @return {any} The user.
 */
async function getUser(userId: string): Promise<any> {
  const userResponse =
      await admin.firestore().collection("users")
          .where("id", "==", userId)
          .limit(1)
          .get();
  if (userResponse.docs.length > 0) {
    return userResponse.docs[0];
  } else {
    return null;
  }
}
```

Where it's called:

```
/**
 * Deletes the user account
 */
export const someFunction = functions.https.onCall(
    async (data, context) => {
      if (!context.auth) {
        return {status: "error", code: 401, message: "Not signed in"};
      }

      try {
        const firestore = admin.firestore();
        const userId = data.userId.trim();
        const userData = await getUser(userId);
        functions.logger.info(
            "User data: ",
            userData
        );

        ...
```

Data structure is as follows

[Data structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UU0E9.png)

Been stuck on it for quite some time now, so any help is MUCH needed.
Thanks in advance

Comment: To clarify, if you are expecting `"id"` to match up with `doc.id` (instead of `doc.data.id`), you need to use `documentId()` instead of `"id"`, but in that case, you'd be better off using `admin.firestore().collection("users").document(userId)` instead. If you add your data structure to your question, it'll be clearer

Comment: @samthecodingman added the data structure as an image.
But responding to your question, "id" is a field in the document

Comment: Thanks for the update, with that structure, you could use the change I suggested above. However, also based on that structure, `data.userId` must be an unexpected value when it hits the server. Did you mean to use `context.auth.uid` to get the authorized user's data?

Comment: @samthecodingman No, I've logged `data.userId` and it's exactly the value for `id` field I want to match.
I have also hardcoded the value inside the where condition and it still returned null.